# How to render ejs in ajax?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, ejs

I want to render ejs with the value after delivering the value in ajax
No errors, it printed "test" on console but ejs is not rendered
Help me please

this is my ajax code

```
                    var s_email = $('#email').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        data : {email : s_email},
                        url : "/process/Oauth_login",
                        type : "POST",
                        success : function(data){}
                    });
```

and server side

```
router.route('/process/Oauth_login').post(function(req, res){    
    var paramEmail = req.body.email;
    Oauth_login(paramEmail, function(err, result){
       if (err){
            res.writeHead(200,{ "Content-Type": "text/html;charset=utf-8"});
            res.write('<h1>Error</h1>');
            res.write('<br><a href="/public/index.html">Go main</a>');
            res.end();
            return;
       }
        if (result) {
            console.log('test');
            res.render("lobby.ejs", {
             id : paramEmail,
             nickname : result[0].nickname
             });
        }
        else{
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public', 'fail_login.html'));
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Have you tried to console.log the data in the ajax call? --> `$.ajax({ ... , success : function(data){ console.log(data); }` If it logs the correct html then you need to insert it somewhere in the page's body. The simplest way is to replace the body itself --> `$('body').html(data)`

Comment: Just realized it would make more sence instead of using ajax just redirect to login url using `location.href = '/process/Oauth_login?email=' + encodeURIComponent(s_email)`

Comment: it logs "lobby.ejs" contents ! 
omg I solved it thank you so much :D